# validations regex

Tags: angular

i need a validations related to angular

validations of control which should accept 2 dots between 3 words

in angular

eg:' san.sa.sa

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this : "\w+.\w+.\w+"

You can find your regexp with this amazing tool ! https://regexr.com/